# Setting up a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add a "following" like functionality to my site but I am having trouble finding the right way to use a polymorphic association. A user needs to be able to follow 3 different classes, these 3 classes do not follow the user back. I have created a user following user in the past but this is proving to be more difficult.

My Migration was

```
 class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :relations_id   
      t.string :relations_type    
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
 end
```

My Relationship model is

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :relations_id
  belongs_to :relations, :polymorphic => true
  has_many :followers, :class_name => "User"
end
```

In my User model

```
has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "supporter_id", :dependent => :destroy
```

and in the other 3 models

```
has_many :relationships, :as => :relations
```

**Am I missing something with setting up this association?**

Comment: Have you tried testing this via the console?  Make sure you run your migrations as well.  What are the 'other 3 models'?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "supporter_id"` ?

Comment: sorry the "supporter_id" was a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically have it right, except for a few minor errors:

- `attr_accessible :relations_id` is redundant. Remove it from your `Relationship` model.
- Both `Relationship` and `User` models call `has_many` to associate with each other. `Relationship` should call `belongs_to` because it contains the foreign key.
- In your `User` model, set `:foreign_key => "follower_id"`.

---

Here is how I would do it.

Have a `Follow` middle class with polymorphic association on the `followable` content side and has_many on the `follower` user side (user has many follows).

First, create a `follows` table:

```
class CreateFollows < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :follows do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.references :followable, :polymorphic => true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Replace `Relationship` model with a `Follow` model:

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :followable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :followers, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Include in `User` model:

```
has_many :follows, :foreign_key => :follower_id
```

Include in your three followable classes:

```
has_many :follows, :as => :followable
```

You can now do this:

```
TheContent.follows   # => [Follow,...]  # Useful for counting "N followers"
User.follows         # => [Follow,...]
Follow.follower      # => User
Follow.followable    # => TheContent
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I am now running into problem implementing the follow and unfollow form as long as the create action. Any tips ?