# Submit Form and Create action for a Polymorphic Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, polymorphic-associations

I received help  [Setting up a polymorphic association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890497/setting-up-a-polymorphic-association)

I am now having trouble implementing the submit form and create action. A user just needs to follow and unfollow each model.

In my Follow Controller

```
 class FollowsController < ApplicationController
       before_filter :find_supports

  def create
    @relation = find_supports
    @follow = @relation.find(params[:follow])
    current_user.follows.follow!(@follow)
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
    end
  end

 def destroy
   @follows = Follow.find(params[:id]).followable
    current_user.unfollow!(@follows)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
    end
 end

  private
  def find_supports
    params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
         return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
     else
       nil
     end
    end
  end
end
```

In my Follow Form, which is rendered at on my polymorphic models

**EDIT**

```
 <%= form_for @cause.follows.build(params[:follow]) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followable_id %></div>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followable_type %></div>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :follower_id %></div>

 <div class="create-button"><%= f.submit "Follow" %></div>
    <% end %>  <!-- I now get the values for followable_id and followable_type, but it         
               wont get grab the follower_id and I get an error in the create action -->
```

and in my User Model, I have these 3 methods

```
   def following?(follow)
       follows.find_by_followable_id(follow)
   end
   def follow!(followable)
       follows.create![]    ##I have tried many different params here
   end
   def unfollow!(followable)
       follows.destroy(params[:followable_id]).destroy
   end
```

I cannot get the follower_id, followable_id and followable_type to save properly. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance, I have spent many hours with this.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having a similar problem with create on a polymorphic association.

Comment: @lflores yes I did. I will add my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved my issues. The answer is using AJAX and Devise helper method current_user

Form Partial

```
  <%= form_for @relation.supports.build(params[:support]), :remote => true do |f| %>
   <div><%= f.hidden_field :supporter_id, :value => current_user.id %></div>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :supportable_id %></div>
   <div><%= f.hidden_field :supportable_type %></div>
   <%= f.submit "Support", :class => "support-button" %>
   <% end %>
```

My Controller

```
class SupportsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :find_relation

def create
  @relation.supports.create!(params[:support])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :back }
  format.js
 end
end

def destroy
 @relation.supports.find(params[:id]).destroy
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to :back }
   format.js
 end
end

private
 def find_supports(instance_params)
   class_name = instance_params["supportable_type"].classify.constantize
   class_name.find(instance_params["supportable_id"])
 end 

def find_relation
  @relation = find_supports(params[:support])
end
end
```

Also, add a before_filter in all the controllers that render the form to find the correct object. This will allow you use the same form partial with all your polymorphic classes.

```
    def find_supports
       @relation = YourClass.find(params[:id])
    end
```