# How to create a model with multiple tables in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails application I am linking into a MySQL database from the legacy PHP application. The naming conventions are incorrect, so am making use of self.table_name to connect models to their respective tables.

I have a requirement to show information from multiple tables into one resource. All these tables have the same column structure. Can I create a model that pulls information from each of these tables? How do I do that? I have been playing around with find_by_sql but am yet to have any success

EDIT: This is all to be read only, no updating is required.

Comment: can't you use a view? so you could map this tables in one table, and fix the naming in one go.

Comment: @Rufinus thanks for your comment, sounds like a good idea, any chance you could provide a code example?

Comment: @Rufinus - What about saving the models? Which table should it go to? You can't save to the view.

Comment: @BroiSatse says who? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html - there are limitions, but it can work.

Comment: @bnussey: sorry, im more the php guy :D

Comment: @Rufinus - 'To be more specific, a view is not updatable if it contains any of the following: (...) UNION (...)`. There is no one-to-one mapping from view element to table element in this case.

Comment: Hey @Rufinus thankfully it is all read only

Answer (score 0):

From your question I believe you are planning to load a other models from one particular model. My suggest is to use a polymorphic relationship.

```
class MainModel
  has_many :sub_model, polymorphic: true
end

class Item1
  belong_to :main_model, as: :sub_model
end

class Item2
  belong_to :main_model, as: :sub_model
end
```

Now in the view you will have to write your data as follows.

```
@main_model.sub_model.name |  @main_model.sub_model.value
```

Since all the other models/tables has the same structure you won't have to change the attribute.

And when updating it, you just accept the values of the sub_models as a nested attribute and they will update the corresponding model.

For more details on how to setup a polymorphic relationship visit [Setting up a polymorphic association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890497/setting-up-a-polymorphic-association)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried setting this up but it doesn't seem to work.. is that because I am using MySQL tables that don't follow the naming conventions of ActiveRecord? I thought because of this I wouldn't be able to set any foreign keys or any relationships

Comment: I'm getting: Unknown key: :polymorphic.

Comment: This code is database independent. Check this question for more details on how to set up a polymorphic association. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890497/setting-up-a-polymorphic-association

Comment: Hey, so this will work even though the naming conventions of ActiveRecord haven't been followed as it's a legacy database? I am still getting errors, and was thinking it was because of this